# (Isomorphic) Back-end rendering of routes and ajax-based react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to build an isomorphic react app. I use express as a back-end. I have a static router with an App component in it. I catch any request and use renderToString like this:

(code below is incomplete and might have syntactic mistakes - did not run it through IDE)

server.jsx:

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
 const itemIDs =
 ['myFirstItemID', 'mySecondItemID', 'myThirdItemID'] // fetched from DB

 const renderedApp = 
 ReactDOM.renderToString(<StaticRouter> <App itemIDs=itemIDs /> </StaticRouter>);

 res.render("index", { renderedData: renderedApp });
 res.end();
}
```

App.jsx - render method only

```
render() {
    const renderedRoutes = this.props.itemIDs.map(itemID => (<Route path={itemID} render={() => <Item ItemID={itemID}/>} />)
    );
        return (
                    <Switch>
                        {renderedRoutes}
                        <Route component={ItemsContainer itemIDs=itemIDs} />
                    </Switch>
        )
    }
```

ItemsContainer.jsx - render method only

```
render() {
      const ItemSummaries = this.props.itemIDs.map(itemId => <ItemPreview itemId={itemId}/>)

      return (
        <div>
            {ItemSummaries}
          </div>
      )
```

ItemPreview.jsx - render method only

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Link to={"/" + this.props.itemId}>
        <h2>an item</h2>
    </Link>
        </div>
    )
```

Item.jsx - componendDidMount and render

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get("/api/items?itemID=" + this.props.itemID)
.then((data) => this.state.itemData = data);

render() {
    return (
        <div>
          //use itemData here
    </Link>
        </div>
    )
```

Client.jsx - served to the client (uses same App.jsx component)

```
const MyRoutedApp = () =>
        (<BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>);

ReactDOM.hydrate(<MyRoutedApp/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I feel like something is very wrong in my approach, but I'm not sure what.
The problems that I have are:

- The ItemIDs are used only within the server to generate routes. Once the App is available at the client, I no longer have routes, so the BrowserRouter doesn't work. I can get the routes using ajax, but this results in having the initial render happen before I have the needed data, which results in always seeing the ItemsContainer (the default route) for a few frames no matter at which URL I am.
- What are my options in order to renderToString a component that relies on ajax within componentDidMount to decide its render() content (Item.jsx)?
- Last but not least - is this actually a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

So one way I've found to solve the first problem is to render the routes within the initial index page response (within a `<script>` tag) and then have the App constructor handle the routes based on where it's being rendered:

- if rendered by server - take the props passed
- if rendered in browser - take the global object.

Here's how it'd look like in code:

Somewhere within index page (EJS template):

```
//
<script>const globalRoutes = <%- JSON.stringify(renderedRoutes) %> </script>
//
```

"/" request handler:

```
var fetchedRoutes; //your routes
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {

    var context = {};
    const routedApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        React.createElement(
            StaticRouter,
            { location: req.url, context: context },
            React.createElement(App, {routesData: fetchedRoutes})
  )
      );

    res.render("index", { renderedData: routedApp, renderedRoutes: fetchedRoutes });
    res.end();

});
```

How App handles routes:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { routesData: this.isBrowser() ? globalRoutes : this.props.routesData }
    }
```